# Unable to kick out duplicate results using set

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape all the links located under the table titled as `England` and then using those links when my script reaches the inner page then it will scrape the next page link. I know If I fix the xpaths used within the script, I may get unique next page urls.

However, the main goal here is to identify why my script is producing duplicates even when I used `set()`.

My script:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "http://tennishub.co.uk/"

processed_links = set()
processed_nextpage_links = set()

def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(response.text)

    unprocessed_links = [urljoin(link,item.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]) for item in tree.xpath('//*[@class="countylist"]')]
    for nlink in unprocessed_links:
        if nlink not in processed_links:
            processed_links.add(nlink)
    get_nextpage_links(processed_links)

def get_nextpage_links(itemlinks):
    for ilink in itemlinks:
        response = requests.get(ilink)
        tree = fromstring(response.text)
        titles = [title.xpath('.//a/@href')[0] for title in tree.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]') if title.xpath('.//a/@href')]
        for ititle in titles:
            if ititle not in processed_nextpage_links:
                processed_nextpage_links.add(ititle)

        for rlink in processed_nextpage_links:
            print(rlink)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(link)
```

Results I'm getting like:

```
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Durham/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Durham/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Durham/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Cheshire/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Derbyshire/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Durham/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Cheshire/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Derbyshire/2
/tennis-clubs-by-county/Durham/2
```

Comment: also you don't have to keep the records in the `set()` for the whole time, you can append them to a `list` using `.append()` and then turn them into a set at the end `unique_records = set(list_of_all_records)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following script. Turn out that your xapth got some flaws which were parsing a certain block out of several as what @tripleee has already mentioned (supposedly) in his comment. I used `set()`  in a slightly different way in the follwong script. Now, it should produce unique links.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = "http://tennishub.co.uk/"

def get_links(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(response.text)
    crude_links = set([urljoin(link,item) for item in tree.xpath('//*[@class="countylist"]//a/@href') if item])
    return crude_links

def get_nextpage(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    tree = fromstring(response.text)
    titles = set([title for title in tree.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]//a/@href') if title])
    return titles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for next_page in get_links(link):
        for unique_link in get_nextpage(next_page):
            print(unique_link)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing all the links you have collected so far every time you call `get_nextpage_links`.

I guess you will want to remove the `print` entirely, and just print the list when you are done, ideally outside of any `def` (make your functions reusable, and defer any external side effects to the calling code).

A better solution without global variables might be to have `get_links` collect a set and return it, passing a reference to the set to `get_nextpage_links` whenever you call it, and (obviously) have that add any new links.

Because you are using a set, there is no particular need to check if a link is already in the set before adding it. There is no way to add a duplicate to this data type.

Comment: Probably unrelated to this question. I'm not going to visit an unfamiliar web site but typically, you would find that your XPath expression extracts only a subset of the links you wanted, perhaps because they are not consistently encoded, or because you have an error in the XPath specification.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you’re calling

```
        for rlink in processed_nextpage_links:
            print(rlink)
```

you are printing it because your for loop is inside the for loop adding the link in your set